# Creative way to display tables with 35 columns

Tags: php, jquery, scroll, content-management-system, tabular

I have a form where users are entering 35 different fields.

I have a Content Management System where I want to display the results of an order on the form.

I've thought about adding a horizontal scrollbar inside the table, or limiting the table to the 10 most important columns and then making it so the administrator has to click on an entry to view all of the information on its own details page.

Do you know any creative ways that I can display the 35 fields on one page?

Comment: You might want to try asking this type of question at http://uxexchange.com/.  It's (very) similar to stackoverflow.com, only geared towards UX and UI design questions like this one.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the tip about uxexchange.com. Is the the activity there as much as here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard Master/Detail Form should work.  The table/grid would have key pieces of data and below it, the detail form would have all the details in a user friendly layout.  To see the detail a user simply needs to select or click a row in the table/grid and the information rendered in the detail area is updated by the On_Click/On_Hover/etc event.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like a really good idea! Do you know any links or screenshots that show the use of this?

Comment: I've never done it in PHP but I have done it in ASP.NET.  Unfortunately the web searches so far keep landing on how to do it with Dreamweaver which I don't know if that will help you or not.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will fit your needs, but the [jQuery ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin might be an interesting alternative to just a plain horizontal scrollbar.

---

Edit: There is another addon you might want to look at called [columnManager](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/columnmanager/demo/demo.html).

Comment: That column Manager looks really interesting! Thanks for the tip! +1

Answer (score 0):

I have had instances dealing with grids that are wide. In my own opinion, I think it is best to use the browser's (horizontal) scroll bar instead of having an "inner" (horizontal) scrollbar. A problem with http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Also, no clicks are involved or whatsoever. The user will be able to see everything by just scrolling. On the other hand, allowing the user to hide/show columns would also be good.

Comment: It may be interesting to combine the scrollTo technique with the 'fixed table header' plugin: http://www.aravindanr.com/2009/07/28/fixed-header-table-using-jquery/